# jquery ui spinner buttons messed up styling when using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, spinner

I want to use the jquery-ui spinner along with jquery-mobile on my site but the styling of the spinner's buttons are messed up. It seems that jquery is using the mobile styling although I wrapped the spinner in a div and used a scope on the jquery-ui styling sheet.

The code:

```
    <title>Spinner</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jQuery/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jQuery/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#spinner").spinner();
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="myScope">
            <input id="spinner" name="value" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Example: http://gioco.bplaced.net/jQueryTest/spinner.html